# The best and fastest way to add an external js file: append on head or using $.getscript()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

I want to know if, for performance, is better to use `$.getScript()` or appending the js file on `head`.

**Append with Javascript**

```js
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "file.js";
$("head").append(s);
```

**Using Jquery/Ajax**

```
$.getScript("file.js");
```

I tried also this method but doesn't work...

```
jQuery.ajax({               
  url: "file.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

Comment: If you were going to append with Javascript without JQuery then you would need to use something like `var head = document.getElementsByTag("head"); head[0].appendChild(s);`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on when you load the script. By default all scripts in the `<head>` will block the rendering of the page until they have been loaded, except if the `async` property is set on them, e.g. `<script src="script.js" async>`.

The `async` property on `<script>` tags will simply tell the browser not to interrupt the parsing & rendering processes to load the script.

I am unsure how the following works, but If inside your `<head>` you call a script that does not have the `async` property and that script adds a new `<script>` tag to the `<head>` at a position that has not yet been parsed (for example below the script that is adding the tag), I am unsure if it will make a difference with simply including another `<script>` tag in your `<head>` from the start.

Best for performance would be to include a script at the bottom of your page, below the `</html>` closing tag. If you include a `<script>` tag there, that script will be loaded after all the HTML has been parsed, which is usually better for scripts that can wait that long before needing to be executed.

Thus, to answer your question, probably in most cases adding the script using Javascript (`$.getScript()`) would be faster, but probably using the `async` property will be even faster than that. If combined with the `defer` property (which defers loading until the page has been parsed), it would be even faster.

Comment: I believe the `<script>` tags should be just inside the closing body `</body>` tag. It's also worth a look at the origin of the external js. The browser may treat the ajax call from JQuery's getScript() differently than loading the script directly from the page.